# How do I implement Orchestration on WCF using MessageInspector

Tags: wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

I have a WCF Service, And I inspect that using MessageInspector ( inherit IDispatchMessageInspector)

I want to do some thing before running service and result of that ı want not run service.

I want to prevent client call but client dont receive exception.

Can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario looks like the post in the MSDN WCF forum entitled "[IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest - skip operation and manually generate custom response instead](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/55ef7692-25dc-4ece-9dde-9981c417c94a)". If this is what you need (when you receive a message in the inspector, you decide that you want to skip the service operation, but return a message to the client and the client should not see an exception), then this answer should work for you as well. Notice that you'll need to create the response message in the same format as the client expects, otherwise you'll have an exception.

This code uses three of the (many) WCF extensibility points to achieve that scenario, a message inspector (as you've mentioned you're using), a message formatter and an operation invoker. I've blogged about them in an ongoing series about WCF extensibility at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx.

```
public class Post_55ef7692_25dc_4ece_9dde_9981c417c94a
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "ITest", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding result = new BasicHttpBinding();
        return result;
    }
    public class MyOperationBypasser : IEndpointBehavior, IOperationBehavior
    {
        internal const string SkipServerMessageProperty = "SkipServer";
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyInspector(endpoint));
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            dispatchOperation.Formatter = new MyFormatter(dispatchOperation.Formatter);
            dispatchOperation.Invoker = new MyInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker);
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
        }

        class MyInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
        {
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint;
            public MyInspector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
            {
                this.endpoint = endpoint;
            }

            public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {
                Message result = null;
                HttpRequestMessageProperty reqProp = null;
                if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
                {
                    reqProp = request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
                }

                if (reqProp != null)
                {
                    string bypassServer = reqProp.Headers["X-BypassServer"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bypassServer))
                    {
                        result = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, this.FindReplyAction(request.Headers.Action), new OverrideBodyWriter(bypassServer));
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }

            public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
                Message newResult = correlationState as Message;
                if (newResult != null)
                {
                    reply = newResult;
                }
            }

            private string FindReplyAction(string requestAction)
            {
                foreach (var operation in this.endpoint.Contract.Operations)
                {
                    if (operation.Messages[0].Action == requestAction)
                    {
                        return operation.Messages[1].Action;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            class OverrideBodyWriter : BodyWriter
            {
                string bypassServerHeader;
                public OverrideBodyWriter(string bypassServerHeader)
                    : base(true)
                {
                    this.bypassServerHeader = bypassServerHeader;
                }

                protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("EchoResponse", "http://tempuri.org/");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("EchoResult");
                    writer.WriteString(this.bypassServerHeader);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
        }

        class MyFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
        {
            IDispatchMessageFormatter originalFormatter;
            public MyFormatter(IDispatchMessageFormatter originalFormatter)
            {
                this.originalFormatter = originalFormatter;
            }

            public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
            {
                if (message.Properties.ContainsKey(MyOperationBypasser.SkipServerMessageProperty))
                {
                    Message returnMessage = message.Properties[MyOperationBypasser.SkipServerMessageProperty] as Message;
                    OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Add(MyOperationBypasser.SkipServerMessageProperty, returnMessage);
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(MyOperationBypasser.SkipServerMessageProperty, returnMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.originalFormatter.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
                }
            }

            public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)
            {
                if (OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.ContainsKey(MyOperationBypasser.SkipServerMessageProperty))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.originalFormatter.SerializeReply(messageVersion, parameters, result);
                }
            }
        }

        class MyInvoker : IOperationInvoker
        {
            IOperationInvoker originalInvoker;

            public MyInvoker(IOperationInvoker originalInvoker)
            {
                if (!originalInvoker.IsSynchronous)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("This implementation only supports synchronous invokers");
                }

                this.originalInvoker = originalInvoker;
            }

            public object[] AllocateInputs()
            {
                return this.originalInvoker.AllocateInputs();
            }

            public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
            {
                if (OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.ContainsKey(MyOperationBypasser.SkipServerMessageProperty))
                {
                    outputs = null;
                    return null; // message is stored in the context
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.originalInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
                }
            }

            public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            public bool IsSynchronous
            {
                get { return true; }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), GetBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyOperationBypasser());
        foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            operation.Behaviors.Add(new MyOperationBypasser());
        }

        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Echo("Hello"));

        Console.WriteLine("And now with the bypass header");
        using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequestProp.Headers.Add("X-BypassServer", "This message will not reach the service operation");
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(
                HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name,
                httpRequestProp);
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.Echo("Hello"));
        }

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: in that solution message reach service operation and then modify message content. But I don't want call to reach service. However  SkipServerMessageProperty is not be used anywhere. Invoker control that property

Comment: If you don't want the call to even reach the service, then your best bet would be to wrap the *client* proxy in another class which implements the same interface, and if some condition is met, then instead of calling the proxy's operation you simply return.